# Slick Slider adaptiveHeight desynchronizes sliders connected via asNavFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

I have three Slick sliders, where one of the sliders looks like browser tabs, while two others are below and change by clicking the tabs. This works perfectly with the help of `asNavFor`. Sometimes the content of the slides of the bottom slider changes. This sometimes creates whitespace between the slider and the element below it.

I tried to add `adaptiveHeight: true` to the bottom slider. Now the height adapts to the content and the whitespace disappears. But now the sliders are not synchronized anymore. First click on Next moves the bottom sliders one slide, but not the tabs slider. Another click on Next moves the tabs slider, but not the top slider.

Has anyone any clue on why this is happening or how I can fix this issue?

Here is my slider code:

```js
$('.phase--top').slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: false,
      // adaptiveHeight: true,
      fade: true,
      asNavFor: '.phase--tabs, .phase--tipp'
    });
    $('.phase--tipp').slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      // adaptiveHeight: true,
      arrows: false,
      fade: true,
      asNavFor: '.phase--tabs, .phase--top'
    });
    $('.phase--tabs').slick({
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      asNavFor: '.phase--tipp, .phase--top',
      dots: false,
      centerMode: false,
      prevArrow: "<button type='button' class='slick-prev pull-left'></button>",
      nextArrow:"<button type='button' class='slick-next pull-right'></button>",
      focusOnSelect: true,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1050,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 700,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    });
```

Edit:
I get this error code in my console on the first click:

> Uncaught TypeError: i.$list.animate is not a function

Edit 2:
I use jquery Version 3.5.1 and Slick Slider Version 1.8.1.

Also here is a Markup of my HTML:

```
<div class="phase--outer">
    <div class="phase--tabs">
            <div class="phase--title"> 
                <img class="phase--icon" src="phase_icon">
                <img class="phase--iconb" src="phase_iconb">
                TITLE
            </div>
            <div class="phase--title"> 
                <img class="phase--icon" src="phase_icon">
                <img class="phase--iconb" src="phase_iconb">
                TITLE
            </div>
            <div class="phase--title"> 
                <img class="phase--icon" src="phase_icon">
                <img class="phase--iconb" src="phase_iconb">
                TITLE
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="phase--top">
            <div class="phase--text"> 
                TEXT 
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="phase--tipp">
            <div class="phase--tipptext"> 
                <img class="phase--tippicon" src="icon_bulb">TIPP:
                <div class="phase--tipp-text">TIPPTEXT</div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I never tried **this specific setup**, but always used `adaptiveHeight` along with `fade` (as you did) **and** arrows shown on the large Slider, not on the small one. I could imagine some weird collisions or incompatibility issues between the multi-slide slider with arrows and the single-slide slider with adaptiveHeight.

Some questions regarding your Setup:

1. Which version of Slick do you use?
2. Which version of jQuery do you use?
3. Do you use the images directly as slides or are they wrapped inside of other elements?

The third question is because there is an issue with the current Slick version (1.8.1) when using `<img />` directly as slides. In that case the `slidesToScroll` property does not work correctly and behaves as a multiple of `slidesToShow`. Additionally the `infinite` property doesn't work in that case either.

I created a Pen [Slick Slider - Multiple Synced](https://codepen.io/tiritm/pen/dyXOjVe) where it seems to work properly. I hope this helps a bit at least.

Comment: I edited my Post to account for your questions. I dont use Images as Slides. My Slides mostly consists of Text and Icon Images.

Comment: @Niqql I updated my Codepen to match your markup a bit better and it's still working there. By the way, jQuery 5.5.1 does not exist, the current version is 3.5.1 as used in the Pen above. Did you mean that?

Comment: Yes, I'm using 3.5.1, it was just a typo. I'll check if I can spot a difference between you Pen and my Code. Thanks for the efford!

Comment: My jQuery installation didnt work properly. Everything works fine now. Thanks again for helping me. I marked your answer as correct, because you helped me find my Issue, provided a working Pen and explained a Bug in the current Slick Version, wich might help people in the future with this bug.